# How to have x-Axis in years if input is in time, in SVG d3 area chart?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, svg

var input = [{1307555600000,786},{1306693800000,506},{1306693800040,986}];
// time, price

I plotted it on Area chart, but on X-Axis I don't want to show all the entities, as input data is large, it is not possible to see all. Instead I just want to show year range.

e.g. x-Axis: [image: X-Axis]

Comment: just give tick number https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Axes.md#ticks